# Unity trying to instantiate enum parameter while adding Active Directory access to OWIN

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, enums, active-directory, unity-container

I was following the instructions in [this blog](https://willwebforfood.wordpress.com/2015/04/01/owin-and-active-directory/), to add Active Directory logins to an existing OWIN Web Application, but at runtime it fails with:

> The type ContextType does not have an accessible constructor.

The calback registration in `Startup.Auto.cs` looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // This is the important part, this is how you will configure the PrincipalContext used throughout your app
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine));
```

The other code looks like this (as per the blog):

```
private readonly PrincipalContext _principalContext;
public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store, PrincipalContext principalContext)
    : base(store)
{
    _principalContext = principalContext;
}

public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
{
    var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()), context.Get<PrincipalContext>());
```

Why is Unity trying to instantiate the enum class at all?

I am using MVC5 under VS 2015 pro.

Comment: My wild guess is that Unity is not trying to instantiate `PrincipalContext` but rather the `ApplicationUserManager` class. This error denotes that Unity is trying to create a class which dependency cannot be resolved. There is a dependency on `PrincipalContext` in the constructor which seems not container-bound. Why is it trying to instantiate it in the first place - I don't know. Probably you register the `ApplicationUserManager` class in the Unity container somewhere (explicitly or implicitly with some convention-over-configuration lib).

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown at? Upon just looking at the above snippets... is it happening in the ApplicationUserManager.Create method where it uses the [context.Get<>] method? I wonder if simply adding a statement like [app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => ContextType.Machine);] just above where the principal context is registered...

Comment: Can you please update your question with how you have setup unity registrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrincipalContext has other constructors where one of the parameters is ContextType, now when you are calling context.Get in following line

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()), context.Get<PrincipalContext>());
```

unity tries to use one of the other constructors with the maximum parameters. this is typical behavior of IOC containers. now if you set your dependency like this

```
container.RegisterType<Foo>(new InjectionFactory(c => new Foo(Bar.Bar1)));
```

then it should work. i haven't tried and example but if you can share bit more of your code i can try to work it out.

Comment: Added `container.RegisterType<PrincipalContext>(new InjectionFactory(x => new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)));` to the Unity RegisterTypes and the error has gone. I must have missed a step somewhere. Just checking the AD usage now.

Comment: There is a second problem in that the principal content needs to be available from the `IOwinContext`, so added a static CreatePrincipalContent() method to my Application UserManager. The only problem now is that it logs in against AD successfully, but goes back to the login as it fights with the standard OWIN ASPNetUsers login system. Time to pull out the ASPNetUsers login system now. Thanks

Comment: You know you could also do that just by running your website under IntegratedSecurity i.e. windows AD security. and you dont need to do all that principal context stuff. i dont remember exactly ATM, did it long time back. so as long as the users is logged on to the OS the website will use logged on user's identity

Comment: That is actually what I wound up doing. AD only requires some web.config settings and nothing else. I will mark you as answer for all your help. Sorry about the bounty.